# Filter classes which implements certain interface using FilteredTypesSelectionDialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I want to filter all the classes from the workspace which implements certain interface using eclipse jdt FilteredTypesSelectionDialog. Is there any way to achieve this?

```java
IJavaElement[] elements = new IJavaElement[] { javaproject };
IJavaSearchScope scope = SearchEngine.createJavaSearchScope(elements);
FilteredTypesSelectionDialog dialog = new FilteredTypesSelectionDialog(root.getShell(), false, null, scope, IJavaSearchConstants.CLASS);
//filter classes which implements an interface
```

Comment: Note that `FilteredTypesSelectionDialog` is an **internal** class which you are not supposed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For subtypes of a given type use

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.createStrictHierarchyScope(IJavaProject, IType, boolean, boolean, WorkingCopyOwner)
```

To use this in a type selection dialog refer to

```
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaUI.createTypeDialog(Shell, IRunnableContext, IJavaSearchScope, int, boolean, String, TypeSelectionExtension)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.